# How to add active class in jQuery calling from active.js file?

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

This active.js file

```
          $(function() {
            $("#navbar-nav li").click(function($) {
                // remove classes from all
                $("li").removeClass("active");
                // add class to the one we clicked
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
        });
```

this is header.php

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/active.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link nav-brand" href="home">home</a>
</li>
```

I've added active in jquery but it's not working

Comment: are you adding li dynamically and is the parent #navbar-nav id correct?

Comment: It's static only not dynamic website yes id is correct only    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                    <li class="nav-item active">
                                        <a class="nav-link nav-brand" href="home">home</a>
                                    </li>

Comment: @MohanKrishnaBhimavarapu In your comment above, `navbar-nav` is a class and not an ID, and your jquery code is looking for an id.

Comment: I've checked both using class and id both are not working not able to get what went wrong in the code

Answer (score 0):

we add active class to clicked item then remove it from its siblings

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-item").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active")
  })
})
```

```css
.active a{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link nav-brand " href="home">home</a>
 </li>
<li class="nav-item ">
  <a class="nav-link nav-brand " href="home">Page A</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item ">
  <a class="nav-link nav-brand " href="home">Page B</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the op already has.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code using `.on` as new version not working for `.click`.
Also replace `#` with `.` as ul has `navbar-nav` as class attribute and not id.

```
$(function() {
      $("ul.navbar-nav").on("click" ,"li", function($) {
            // remove classes from all
            $("ul.navbar-nav li").removeClass("active");
            // add class to the one we clicked
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
```